# Upload to database and storage at the same time in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my android app I am using client side fan-out to upload data to multiple places in database at the same time to avoid problems for example in case of lost internet connection. Here is example code from Firebase blog:

```
Map updatedUser = new HashMap();
newPost.put("name", "Shannon");
newPost.put("username": "shannonrules");

Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");

Map fanoutObject = new HashMap();
fanoutObject.put("/users/1", updatedUser);
fanoutObject.put("/usersWhoAreCool/1", updatedUser);
fanoutObject.put("/usersToGiveFreeStuffTo/1", updatedUser);

ref.updateChildren(fanoutObject); // atomic updating goodness
```

But now I would also like to upload image file to storage alongside that data. Is that posiible to do that at the same time?

Comment: As Cedric answered, there is no way to write to multiple Firebase features in a single operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can synchronize calls to Firebase Database and storage. The documentation does not mention it anywhere.

But just so you know: Firebase will save any requests made by `updateChildren()` in the cache if they cannot be sent due to loss of connection. When the user reconnects, Firebase will then dispatch all the cached requests in the same order that they were saved.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do these two tasks *concurrently* would be to first determine your file path in Storage, and kick off the upload, then also use that file path to update the database.  That's about as good as you'll get.

However, most of the time you want to store the "download URL" of the uploaded file in the database, instead of the path in the storage bucket.  This makes it easier for clients to go directly to the content without having to "look up" the download URL first.  In this case, you really do need to wait for the storage upload to complete first, get the download URL from the UploadTask, then update the database with that string.  You can't know the download URL *before* the upload completes.

Comment: How i did it? I have upload image to  storage and to next procedure is add the informations (included downloadUrl uri) to Firestore Collection, but the add on firestore collection terminate much before of addition in Storage.